# ¿Cómo guardo el valor en SQL server de varios Checkbox que se encuentran en un Checkbox List de ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

De ante mano mil gracias por su apoyo, tengo un `<asp:CheckBoxList>` con dos `<asp:ListItem>` de esta forma:

```
<div>
    <asp:Label Text="Tipo de asociado de negocio" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="T_Asociado" runat="server" CssClass="MRadio" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
         <asp:ListItem Value="Cliente">Cliente</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="Proveedor">Proveedor</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```

estoy intentando guardar el valor de cada uno en un registro de **SQL Server** y los guarda sin problema, pero puede darse el caso que el usuario le pueda dar a los dos `CheckBox` y cuando voy a revisar la base de datos para verificar que guardara los dos valores, me guarda solo el primero.

**VISTA DEL CHECKBOXLIST**

[image: VISTA DEL CHECKBOXLIST]

**DATO GUARDADO EN LA BASE DE DATOS SQL SERVER**

[image: DATO GUARDADO EN SQL SERVER]

¿Cómo podre hacer para que me guarde los dos ítems en caso de que el usuario necesite seleccionar los dos elementos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una salida rápida puede ser algo como esto:

```
string[] asociados = new string[T_Asociado.Items.Count];
string columna BD = string. Empty; 
for (int i=0; i<T_Asociado.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (T_Asociado.Items[i].Selected)
        asociados[i] = T_Asociado.Items[i].Text;
}
columna_BD = string. Join(",", asociados);
```

Entonces, esa variable **columna_BD** es la que envías a tu base de datos como valor. Para obtener los valores desde la base de datos haces el proceso inverso del que te envié.

```
//Leer desde la base de datos y cargar en una variable
string columna_BD = DATO_DESDE_BD; //En el formato Cliente,Proveedor
string[] valores = columna_BD.Split(',');
foreach(var item in T_Asociado.Items)
{
    //Tu lógica de check para el item de tu CheckBoxList
}
```